# How to strip HTML from RSS to Yammer message

Tags: azure-devops, yammer, power-automate

I created a Flow that publishes [RSS](https://status.dev.azure.com/_rss) to Yammer. The RSS feed contains Azure DevOps status updates, provided my Microsoft.

**Flow definition:**

[image]

**Actual result:**

[image]

**Question: How can I publish this RSS message without HTML tags in the message output?**

Comment: Did you try the HTML to Text action at all? The feed at https://status.dev.azure.com/_rss has the HTML embedded in the feed so you'd need to clean that before pushing the text onwards to Yammer.

Comment: Thanks @BrianLyttle. Can you add that as an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: Don't worry about  it. I learned something about Flow, and I'm glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the **Html to text** action.
To find this new action, search for HTML when you add an action.

Thanks to @BrianLyttle for pointing this out.

**Fixed flow and output:**

[image: Fixed flow]

Comment: On a related note, you can insert the Html to text action by adding it as a last step, then use drag & drop to move it where it belongs.